# Проблемы с Django после деплоя на сервер

Tags: django

Залил сайт на Django на сервер. Смотрю в метрике на сайт заходят куча роботов на несуществующие страницы типа "git.gitlab.git.git.mail.kvg". Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это может быть? Даже не представляю куда копать...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]